# Filter datatable with 2 criteria using linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I want to filter a datatable's rows with 2 criteria using Linq technique. However, somehow I am unable to the my expected result. It returns  I am pretty sure my field name and its value is correct. Below is my code for filtering.

```
Dim dt as DataTable = Me.TestDataSet.Tables("table1").Copy()
If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
     Dim filteredRows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = (From n In dt.AsEnumerable()
               Where n.Field(Of Date)("DueDate") = Today.Date And n.Field(Of String)
               ("Status") = "Open" Select n)
     Dim filteredDT As DataTable
     If Not (filteredRows.Count > 0) Then
         filteredDT = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable()
     End If
     dt.Clear()
End If
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected result, and what you get currently? Your code looks fine as far as I can see.

Comment: Why bother with linq? Just use a `DataView` to filter a `DataTable`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I already sorted out this problem. The problem was at another part of the code. Thank you guys.